# android ndk and opengl-es 1.0/1.1 - 2D graphics

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm working on a game that uses opengl 1.1. I hope to use opengl to print a texture directly to the screen in 2D. I'm only just getting started. I'm following a blog post at this location:

http://quirkygba.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-native-coding-in-c.html

I cannot get it to work, though. Enclosed is a large piece of code that should print something to the screen. Anything would be good. Now it just prints black. If I uncomment the 'glClearColor' and 'glClear' lines I can get a color to the screen, so I know that I can call an opengl command and have it work. It's almost as if 'glDrawTexiOES' doesn't work. I'm using ndk 7b and I've tested on the emulator as well as a 2.2 and 2.3 device. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Android.mk file ////////////////////////

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := something
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := something.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lGLESv1_CM 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

// something.c ////////////////////////////////

//some other includes here.
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES/glext.h>

#define  LOG_TAG              "something-jni"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define RGB565(r, g, b)  (((r) << (5+6)) | ((g) << 6) | (b))

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0 

#define TEX_WIDTH   256
#define TEX_HEIGHT  256

#define TEX_DIMENSION   256

static uint16_t *pixbuf = NULL;
static GLuint   texture;
static int screen_width, screen_height;

static void check_gl_error(const char* op)
{
    GLint error;
    for (error = glGetError(); error; error = glGetError())
    LOGE("after %s() glError (0x%x)\n", op, error);
}



void init(void)
{
    int i;
    int tex_width, tex_height;


    tex_width = TEX_WIDTH;
    tex_height = TEX_HEIGHT;

    GLint crop[4] = { 0, tex_height, tex_width, - tex_height };

    pixbuf = malloc(tex_width * tex_height * 2);
        for (i = 0; i < TEX_DIMENSION * TEX_DIMENSION ; i ++ ) {
        pixbuf[i] = 0xffff;//RGB565(0xf,0,0);
    }

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    check_gl_error("glTexParameteri");

    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    check_gl_error("glTexParameteri");

    glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, crop);
    check_gl_error("glTexParameteriv");

    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    check_gl_error("glShadeModel");

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 
        GL_RGB, 
        tex_width, tex_height, 
        0, 
        GL_RGB,
        GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, 
        pixbuf);
    check_gl_error("glTexImage2D");


    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_DITHER);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_FOG);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
    check_gl_error("glDepthMask");

    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    check_gl_error("glDisable");

    //glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, screen_width, screen_height);

    check_gl_error("glDrawTexiOES");

}

// JNI methods for something.c ////////////////


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_..._Panel_JNIinit(JNIEnv * env, jobject  obj, jint w, jint h)
{
    //screen_width = w;
    //screen_height = h;
    init();

}
```

As I say, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your texture dimensions are power of 2?

Comment: if that's the dimensions of your texture image - then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some code you did not share with us, first thing that I noticed is that you do not create an OpenGL context or surface anywhere. You should study how EGL needs to be used in Android NDK.